# MySQL, как вставить массив

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть массив $test = ["1", "Лалала", "И другой текст"].
Как мне этот массив отправить в ячейку mysql и получить обратно же? Пытался сделать с json_encode, не выходит.

Comment: то есть вы не считаете нужным нам сообщить, как именно вы пытались делать с json_encode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего не хранить массивы в ячейках базы данных, а использовать отдельные ячейки для каждой строки. Но если очень хочется то так:

```
<?php

$test = ["1", "Лалала", "И другой текст"];

// записываем в базу данных
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (:data);";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([':data' => json_encode($test)]);

// читаем из базы
$query = "SELECT data FROM tbl;";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


$result = json_decode($row['data'], true);

print_r($result);
```

[PHP MySQL online json_encode](https://phpize.online/?phpses=74d06d1211bb9c6a5f5dcc6a0b298eb1&sqlses=4e68a7394fef2c33e9886ef1ba7336d2&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)